# Is there a limit on how much hard drive space a computer can handle?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-space

I'm thinking of getting a new SSHD for my early 2011 13" MBP, and if I do, I had the idea to give my 500GB HDD to my friend who has a 2007 MacBook (white polycarbonate). He seems to think that his computer can only take 80 and 120GB hard drives. Is this true?

Comment: If you are talking as internal (build in) drive that might be correct, not so for external.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Might? Is there a way to check anywhere?

Comment: The Apple spec says so here https://support.apple.com/kb/sp18?locale=en_US ...but read this lso https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Core+Duo+Hard+Drive+Replacement/282

Answer (score 2):

The only limit would be with the format/filesystem the operating system uses.

You should be fine to put in whatever size drive you want, as long as it physically fits and uses the correct interface (e.g. SATA vs PATA).

Answer (score 0):

The drive will fit (2011 MBP uses standard 9.5 mm thick drives) and it is a SATA II drive that will work nicely with a SATA I port on the 2007 MB thanks to backward compatibility.